# Counting similar facts in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to return true, if a fact (A) is declared only once in the Prolog database, return false otherwise. For instance, if we have:

```
class('Person').
class('Person').
isUniqueClass(A) :- %%% This part I don't know how to do
```

And I query `isUniqueClass('Person').` I want to return false. However, if we have:

```
class('Person').
isUniqueClass('Person') :- %%% Again same thing goes here
```

And I query `isUniqueClass('Person').` I want it to return true.

Answer (score 3):

A shorter version of @twinterer answer, using pattern matching:

```
isUniqueClass(C) :-
 findall(C, class(C), [_]).
```

edit: **refinement**

Instead of 'calling' the predicate, metaprogramming should be done using the appropriate builtins, i.e.

```
isUniqueClass(C) :-
 findall(C, clause(class(C), true), [_]).
```

In this case it doesn't any difference, because a fact can't have side effects...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findall/3` to retrieve a list of all instances, then check the length of the list with `length/2`. If the list has length 1, then the fact was unique.